# subscribing to an observable when another observable completes

Tags: android, multithreading, rx-java, rx-android

Keeping it simple and short, how to subscribe to an observable in another subscriber's onNext() method so that we can only make nested subscription when the current observable completes its execution. Both the subscriptions will be made on separate threads and the requirement is that the first thread must complete its execution before the second thread is started.

```
makeObservable()
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
.subscribe(new Subscriber<User> {
    @override
    void onNext(User user){
    //do something
    //make another subscription here
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't make a new subscription, return another `Observable` and subscribe to it.

```
apiCall()
.subscribeOn(<scheduler>)
.observeOn(<scheduler>)
.flatMap(new Func1<User, Observable<Something>() {
    @Override
    public Observable<Something> call(User user) {
        return Observable.just(<example>);
    }
});
```

edit: when the api call returns, `flatMap` will intercept the stream, and from there, either return an `Observable` or call a function that returns an `Observable` (ie another api call).

Comment: A little elaboration will be helpful

Answer (score 1):

If they're both emitting the same items, use `Observable.concat()`, which subscribes to observable N+1 after observable N completes. But it might be worth it to describe your use case in more detail.

Edit: You should be able to do something like:

```
userClient
.saveUser(user)
.flatMap(userSaveResult -> 
    userClient
   .saveUserDetails(userSaveResult.id, seuser.getDetails))
.onError(...)
```

Comment: I'm using retrofit to return an observable as a result of a call to API, and another observable from another call. First call adds some items to  database and second call makes some updates in the database. Both the calls emit different items (say first observable emits `User` and second emits items related to `User` like `UserInfo`). Obviously updates can only be made if the `User` exists in database which is emitted by first observable.

Comment: I'm not familiar with lambdas yet, I would be grateful if you write it in simple syntax for me to make it understandable.